# Error with appium server, it is launching wll but there is error in the browser when open the localhost

Tags: appium

I am trying to setup appium on my machine( macOS m1 chip) . Installed 2.2.3 version of appium. I launched it using command "appium", and looks like it launched successfully.
[image]

But when I open the url in the browser getting such an error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't open appium in a browser like that, it's not supposed to work.
Instead, use it in an appium client like the [java client](https://github.com/appium/java-client) when creating for example an Android Driver.

example in java:

```java
UiAutomator2Options options = new UiAutomator2Options()
    .setUdid('123456')
    .setApp("/home/myapp.apk");
AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(
    new URL("http://***YOUR_URL***"), options
);
try {
    WebElement el = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath, "//Button");
    el.click();
    driver.getPageSource();
} finally {
    driver.quit();
}
```